# Sparql query with property paths

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Is it possible that an endpoint doesn't answer queries with property paths? I pose the following query in Italian dbpedia  endpoint (http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql):

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
SELECT ?s WHERE {
?s2 skos:broader* <http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Categoria:Archeologia_in_Svezia>.
?s <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?s2
}
```

and I get the following result:

```
 Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 5: syntax error at '*' before '<http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Categoria:Archeologia_in_Svezia>'
in sparql_to_sql_text:(BIF), <Top Level>
```

Comment: Property paths were introduced in SPARQL 1.1.  An endpoint based on an older version of SPARQL (1.0) wouldn't support them, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Italian DBpedia endpoint is still running on [a very old Virtuoso 6.1.0](http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_dbms_name%27%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fname%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_dbms_ver%27%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fversion%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_build_thread_model%27%29%20AS%20%3Fthread%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_build_opsys_id%27%29%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fopsys%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_build_date%27%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fdate%20%29%0D%0A%23%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_lic_owner%27%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fowner%20%29%0D%0A%23%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_lic_serial_number%27%29%20%20AS%20%3Fserial%20%29%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%20%3Fs%20%20%3Fp%20%20%3Fo%20%20%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%201&format=text%2Fhtml&debug=on) (built 2014-09-15, from source code dated around 2010-02-12).  (See the [query I used](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtCheckSvrVersionViaSparql).)

SPARQL 1.1 support was [introduced to the source code](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/blob/stable/6/ChangeLog) around 2012-02-26, for version 6.1.5.

Comment: Thanks! How can I make this query to learn the version of the endpoint?

Comment: Follow the link I gave, to "see the query..." This only works against Virtuoso endpoints, as it uses engine-specific features.